# "test">>: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: java, linux, bash

in my java code I'm doing this:

```
Process process = rt.exec("sudo bash -c \"printf \"test\" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf\"");
```

but bash get me this error:

```
"test">>: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You are making a system call from Java, using bash. What exactly is the bash command supposed to do?  Try to make sure the bash command works form the terminal first, before embedding it into your java code.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the escape character, your `exec` string becomes:

```
sudo bash -c "printf "test" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"
```

which is obviously a grammar error for a shell command.

What you need maybe escape twice:

1. What you need to execute: `printf "test" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`
2. Wrap inside `sudo bash -c`: `sudo bash -c "printf \"test\" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"`
3. Wrap inside `rt.exec()`: `rt.exec("sudo bash -c \"printf \\\"test\\\" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf\"")`

Besides, using `sudo` here, you may run into a unexpected phenomenon on getting password for root privilege.

Comment: This works for the question as asked, but in the real application if there's any variable data involved (e.g. instead of the fixed string "test"), that data will need to be multiply quoted & escaped in ways that depend on the content of the data. It's going to be really hard to do this reliably, and since the resulting shell code executes as root the possible consequences of getting it wrong are ... quite bad. Basically, my point is that running a shell to run `sudo` to run a shell to run a command that does what you actually want isn't a very good way to to things.

Comment: This does not work for the question as asked. `strace` shows the following invalid invocation: `execve("/usr/bin/sudo", ["sudo", "bash", "-c", "\"printf", "\\\"test\\\"", ">>", "/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf\""], 0x7ffe60feab60 /* 58 vars */) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec(String)` is fundamentally broken. It doesn't support any kind of quoting or escaping, so it can not be used to run any command that relies on passing literal whitespace.

Use `Runtime.exec(String[])` instead:

```
Process process = rt.exec(new String[] {
        "sudo", "bash", "-c", "printf \"test\" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf" });
```

Note that this requires `sudo` to be correctly configured for passwordless, non-interactive use, which is not the default. Being able to run the command interactively does *not* imply that the system is correctly configured. You have to read the process's error stream in order to get useful diagnostic information, otherwise it'll simply appear to not work.